# unable to change login menu to logout after user logs in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to build authentication syatem in my website and i am able to successfully register and login but after login my menu bar is still showing me option for login.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="#services">REGISTRATION</a></li>
   <li><a href="download.php">DOWNLOAD</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) === true){
        ?><li><a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li><?php
     }else{
        ?><li><a href="login.php">LOGIN</a></li><?php
     }
     ?>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

what should i do?

Comment: Are you confirm to added session_start(); in your page @user66016

Comment: we can't give you a right answer with the code you supplied , show us where session is created and the top piece of your php code on the pages

Comment: there is no mysqli here, I removed that tag. What is the status of the question? You have answers below that seem to be valid solutions.

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) === true)` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

this piece will fail every time

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) === true){
        ?><li><a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li><?php
     }else{
        ?><li><a href="login.php">LOGIN</a></li><?php  
         ?>
```

normally we check for session like this , check if it is set and check if it not empty and also modified your echo way

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) && (!empty($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
          echo '<li><a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li>';
     }else{
        echo '<li><a href="login.php">LOGIN</a></li>';
     }
     ?>
```

also very important at the top of each page use this code at line 1 and 2 otherwise no session functions will work

```
<?php
session_start();
```